# How to get value of component that data is being transferred to?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I am using a transfer handler to transfer text from one jlabel (A) to another when you drag one jlabel(B) onto another. I got the text to change on B to that of A, but is there a way to identify what the text of B is before you drop the text on it?

This is what changed the text, fairly simple.
But I want to only change the text of B under certain conditions
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                JComponent comp = (JComponent)e.getSource();

```
            TransferHandler handler = comp.getTransferHandler();
            System.out.println(e.toString());


            handler.exportAsDrag(comp, e, TransferHandler.MOVE);

            //repaint();


        }
```

So I tried overriding import data. What it does is that I have two cards (JLabels) and in the beginning they appear in their starting positions in a null layout, so if one card is dragged onto the other, the bottom card goes back to its starting position, which is what home1 and home2 represent. That works, but I want the text to change to the text of the card on top, but that isn't working, so is there a way to get the value of the jlabel that you are dragging onto?

```
TransferHandler transfer = new TransferHandler("text"){
            JComponent sourced;
            Transferable datad;
            @Override
            protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
                if (action == MOVE){
                    ((JLabel) source).setText("");
                    sourced = source;
                    datad = data;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
                return COPY | MOVE;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t)
            {
                if( !((JLabel)comp).getText().equals(""))
                {

                    String text = ((JLabel)comp).getText();
                    if(text.equals(String.valueOf(card1)) )
                    {
                        card1.setBounds(home1);
                        card1.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    if(text.equals(String.valueOf(card2)) )
                    {
                        card2.setBounds(home2);
                        card2.setVisible(true);
                    }


                }
                return true;
            }
        };
```

The full code is here http://pastebin.com/4mxkQY30

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"they appear in their starting positions in a **null layout**.."*  That does not bode well.

Comment: Take a look at [`canImport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#canImport%28javax.swing.TransferHandler.TransferSupport%29). There is still the possibility that the actual data may not be available until the drop actually takes place, but I've only experienced this when dragging files from an external source under the Mac OS

Comment: Ok heres my full code. Most of it works except for after you drag a card into one of the operation card places, you can't drag one of them to the other.
http://pastebin.com/4mxkQY30